# Multiple Hooks, One Extension

Tags: extension, hook

In the [documentation](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/extensions.html) the code to add enable extension hooks is like this

```
$data = array(
    'class'     => __CLASS__,
    'method'    => 'truncate_this',
    'hook'      => 'typography_parse_type_end',
    'settings'  => serialize($this->settings),
    'priority'  => 10,
    'version'   => $this->version,
    'enabled'   => 'y'
);

ee()->db->insert('extensions', $data);
```

So to add multiple hooks to one extension, then should I just simply repeat that code as many times as I wish??

```
$data1 = array(
  ...
);

ee()->db->insert('extensions', $data1);

$data2 = array(
  ...
);

ee()->db->insert('extensions', $data2);
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes. For example....

```
    $hooks = array(
        "template_fetch_template" => "template_fetch_template",
        "typography_parse_type_end" => "typography_parse_type_end"
    );

    foreach ($hooks as $hook => $method) {
        $data = array(
            'class' => __CLASS__,
            'method' => $method,
            'hook' => $hook,
            'settings' => "",
            'priority' => 10,
            'version' => $this->version,
            'enabled' => 'y'
        );
        $this->EE->db->insert($this->EE->db->dbprefix . 'extensions', $data);
    }//###   End of foreach   ###
```