# Proper way to add a new action?

Tags: action

What is the correct way to add a new action to the current list of actions?

Is there a specific EE method to add a new action? Or is it just direct database manipulation(that is, add it via SQL)?

Comment: http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/22383/structure-of-an-extension/22389#22389

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usually it's done on the install method of your addon. Best practice is to take advantage of [ActiveRecord](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html) and a db->insert:

```
$data = array(
    'class' => $this->class,
    'method' => $method
);

ee()->db->insert('actions', $data);
```

You don't need to specify an ACTion ID as this is auto incremented.

You can find a bit more information in the docs for [Module Installation](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/module_tutorial.html#installation-function).

Comment: since v2.6 uses new super global: ee()->db->insert('actions', $data);

Comment: Could you submit your updated code as another answer for clarity?

Comment: Whoops, thanks Peter, well spotted. :) Andrew, Peter has already outlined the updated way of using EE's super global method but I've updated my answer to reflect that.

Comment: Ah, I guess inserting the action to the database directly is the par of course.